# Immediate Task Cancellation

Tags: c#, .net, task, .net-standard, cancellation

I have a question regarding task cancelling using cancellationToken and cancellationTokenSource:

The usual way is as follows:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var t = Task.Run(() => {    
while(true)
  {
    if (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)   
     {  //do stuff }
  }
}, cts.Token);
```

So, the while loop keeps going until the token is requested.
Today, while studying the `Cancel()` method I found that you can use the  `Register()` Method in order to define other code to run when the token is requested, so I was wondering, what if one wrote something like this:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSouce();
token=cts.Token;
token.Register(
() => {
//do something to manage the cancel call
return;
};
) 
var t = Task.Run(() => {
//do stuff 
}, cts.Token);
```

By doing so, the task associated with the `CancellationToken` would immediately stop executing, instead of having to complete the current for iteration like it would in the usual implementation. My question is: is this the right way to immediately stop a `Task` or there is a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Register` doesn't cause a task stop executing it's just a notification that a cancellation has been requested. The main purpose of `Register` is to have ability to cancel asynchronous operations which don't support `CancellationToken` but have their own mechanism of cancellation or can be cancelled indirectly (by closing a socket for example). There are also some tricks described by Stephen Toub [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/) of how to cancel non-cancelable tasks with `Register`. If you however control the execution of a task which should be cancelled it's your responsibility to supply a mechanism to cancel execution. There is no the best approach how to cancel any task - some tasks can be cancelled immediately (you can use `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`), some may require some additional handling (you need to check that cancellation is requested, do something and then throw the exception).

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly the idea is that the return I put in `Register() ` would stop the `//do something to manage the cancel call` part, not the task to which the token is associated to, right? 

I get that the `Register()` by itself won't stop the task, I was wondering if I could use the code inside [the `Register()` ] to stop it [the task].

Comment: In major part of cases the code inside `Register` and inside a task execute in different threads. So you cannot directly stop a task execution inside the `Register`. You need some code inside your task which would react on the cancellation signal and you can of course send this signal from the `Register` but in your case it's kind of overkill because you can just implement logic which would verify cancellation token state in your task. And token isn't associated with any task they're decoupled - instead it can passed as parameter to a task execution method.